# Restarting turns off monitor, but computer stays on

Tags: windows, windows-10, power, reboot, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Since yesterday, my computer just couldn't complete a restart.  I would click the `Windows button > Power > Restart`, and it'd go to the Restart screen. Wheel finishes spinning and the screen goes black.  That's the farthest it goes (within the 10 minutes I waited).

But I know my computer is still on because

1. The fans are still running.
2. The *physical* Windows button on my computer still vibrates on touch.

I've tried disabling services in `msconfig`, but the restart brings me back to the black screen. `sfc /verifyonly` returns that there were no integrity violations.

The strangest part is that tasks on restart (e.g. `Restart your computer to complete installation of hardware updates`) will still operate, despite forcing a shutdown.

What should I do now to get my restart to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was a bug caused by the MalwareBytes Anti-Ransomware Beta installed. It'd continue to run after a shutdown request.

Installing the latest version (Beta 5) fixed the problem.